# Webdriver, PhantomJS and Amazon Elastic Mapreduce

Tags: amazon-web-services, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, elastic-map-reduce

Is it possible to install Webdriver and PhantomJS on the AMIs of Amazon Elastic Mapreduce? If I use sudo apt-get to install all the depedencies in a bootstrap script, does this bootstrap have to run every time I run a task, or do they remain there? Is there a way to pre-build it and copy the source form S3? Is any of this recommended?

Answer (score 0):

EMR runs fairly standard AMIs, so this should not be too difficult.
If you install dependencies in a bootstrap action, any changes you made to this system will stay until you stop the jobflow.

There is no way to use your own AMI with EMR. The recommended way to install software on the cluster is using a bootstrap action.